# Uib accordion toggle issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using `uibAccordion` where the toggling is not happening properly,
If I click 1st repeated element all others also opening. Below is the code.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in scenariosViewAll.collectionBookObject">
        <div class="desc">
            <uib-accordion close-others="true" class="">                                                                                                                             
                <div uib-accordion-group id="{{$index+1}}" class="panel-default" is-open="status.open" is-disabled="true" prevent-click="false" ng-init="status.open = (key == scenariosViewAll.shared.currentSelectedAccordion) ? true : false" ng-class="{'opened': status.open}"  ng-if="value.length > 0">
                    <uib-accordion-heading>
                        <span class="accordion-toggle-wrapper">

                            <span class="accordion-title">
                                {{key}}
                            </span>
                            <span class="pull-right acc-icon-set">
                                <span class="collection-indicator">{{value.length}}</span>
                                   <span class="arrow-toggle">
                                       <button class="btn btn-icon" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="status.open = !status.open;">
                                          <i class="icon" ng-class="{'icon-chevron-up': status.open, 'icon-chevron-down': !status.open}"></i>
                                       </button>
                                   </span>
                               </span>
                           </span>
                    </uib-accordion-heading>
                </div>
            </uib-accordion>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried passing id as `{{index+1}}` and also `close-others="true"`.
But it's not working

Comment: it looks like `<span class="accordion-toggle-wrapper">` is missing a closing tag

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
ng-init="status.open = (key == scenariosViewAll.shared.currentSelectedAccordion) ? true : false"
```

I really don't know what you are binding `status.open` to, but clearly this is wrong and really ambiguous

Simplify it, and give `is-open` a property that refers to a different value for each iterated key/value, for example

```
ng-init="value.ui.isOpen = false;"
is-open="value.ui.isOpen"
```

If you are raelly lazy, and don't need to access these variables inside your controller, just don't bind it to anything

```
ng-init="isOpen = false;" // by now this is redundant and can be removed
is-open="isOpen"
```

this will work because `ngRepeat` created a new scope for every iteration it goes, so a new `isOpen` will be created per such scope.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution by passing index:

```
  <div uib-accordion-group  class="panel-default"  ng-init="status.open = false;" is-open="status.open[$index]"  prevent-click="false"  ng-class="{'opened': status.open}"  ng-if="value.length > 0">
```

Comment: this will break if you paginate or filter your ng-repeat